# Where are TFS Admin Console Settings Saved?

Tags: tfs, administration

this may sound like a silly question but our IT department wants us to use their approved backup tool instead of using the standard back solution that comes packaged within TFS2010. My question is, is there a config file holding all settings found within the TFS Admin Console or are all these values saved within the TFS_Configuration table.

Please note that we are using TFS2010

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings are indeed stored in the config database.